# How to make rechargeable trimmer work without battery?

Tags: dc-motor

I had a rechargeable beard trimmer which was out of work as battery was not charging anymore so yesterday I took out the rechargeable battery and decided to run it directly. As motor needed dc current I provided It through nokia charger and voila motor rotates however when I put the blades back on motor, motor has some vibrations but can't rotate the blades. For which I was thinking voltage or current may be small but when I wire the trimmer to D cell battery blades work. So here why motor is not able to rotate blades when run on a mobile charger, and works well on D cell battery?  When charger provides more voltage than D cell battery. D cell as all know 1.5v whereas charged gives 9v.

Answer (score 6):

Because the charger can't put out the current the motor requires.  As a result, its voltage collapses below 1.5 V.

Comment: Hopefully this answer won't be taken as advice to find a 9V PSU which DOES provide enough current.

Comment: Also, some chargers (maybe/maybe not this particular one) will put out "sensing" pulses with very little actual power, until proper (expected) resistance/residual charge of a rechargeable battery is sensed.